# javax to jakarta migration: glassfish JAXB 4.x reads jakarta.xml.bind.annotations* but not javax.xml.bind.annotations.*

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jakarta-migration

## The context

I'm unmarshalling XML to Java using the following library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The unmarshalling code looks like:

```
 MyClass instance = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class)
                               .createUnmarshaller()
                               .unmarshal(new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader()
                                    .getResourceAsStream("myfile.xml")), MyClass.class)
                               .getValue();
```

It's working well.

## The issue

I'm trying to migrate to the version 4.0.2 of the library:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When running the code, an error occurs:

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "someType". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
```

## The analysis

In my class hierarchy has two classes "SomeType" (in different namespace). The two classes are annotated by `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType`. The class hierarchy is packaged as a library and is shared amongst several applications.

When running with `jaxb-runtime` 2.3.1, the JAXB class `ClassInfoImpl` reads the `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType` annotation:

```
    this.elementName = this.parseElementName(clazz);
    XmlType t = (XmlType)this.reader().getClassAnnotation(XmlType.class, clazz, this);
    this.typeName = this.parseTypeName(clazz, t);
```

But when running with `jaxb-runtime` 4.0.2, the JAXB class `ClassInfoImpl` reads the new `jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType` (notice the `jakarta` prefix instead of the `javax` prefix).

Of course the `XmlType` annotation cannot be found (because it's not the same package), so the error occurs.

## The question

Is there another solution than update the classes from my library by changing from `javax` to `jakarta` annotations ?

Comment: No there is not. This is the main disadvantage of Jakarta EE 9 and up - all existing code that uses `javax` needs to switch to `jakarta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAXB 4 is part of JakartaEE 10 whereas JAXB 2.3 is part of JavaEE 8

The major change is the change of packages from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` starting from JakartaEE 9 (see [here](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/05/end-of-javax-package/) for details about this huge change in Java ecosystem).

The eclipse foundation that is now in charge from JakartaEE has created [this tool (eclipse transformer)](https://github.com/eclipse/transformer) for helping users with that kind of migration where it's difficult to change codebase where users wants to go with JakartaEE world.

If you cannot change your java source (based on `javax` packages), and this source is bundled in a specific jar that is used by your application (which should be the case since jaxb4 is jdk11 baseline and you didn't complain about compilation error about undefined `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType` since `jaxb-runtime` is no more included in JDK starting from JDK9), you may be interested to use the [eclipse maven transformer plugin](https://github.com/eclipse/transformer/tree/main/maven-plugins/transformer-maven-plugin).

Hope that will help you get it work as wanted.

Comment: This answers to my initial question ("is there another way"), but in the meantime, I already migrated my library.

Comment: In my opinion, it's the best and future-proof option to migrate library but on libraries that can't get migrated, it's a good option